# Conditionally set ENV var based on hostname in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

How can I set an ENV var in my Dockerfile based on the hostname? I tried this:

```
RUN if [ hostname = "foo" ]; then ENV BAR "BAZ"; else ENV BAR "BIFF"; fi
```

But that failed with

```
ENV: not found
```

Comment: But the hostname will be the random hostname of the container - this is never going to work...

Comment: However, I suspect build args are what you want: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg

Comment: I do the same thing with other commands like `ln -s` and it works fine.

Comment: build args will not work for me. From the docs `these values don’t persist in the intermediate or final images like ENV values do` I need the ENV var to exist in the final image. It is used for a config option to a database and I need to have different options on different hosts.

Comment: You should pass in an environment variable to the runtime when you execute `docker run`. The values in your Dockerfile are static, and won't change based on the host you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> RUN if [ hostname = "foo" ]; then ENV BAR "BAZ"; else ENV BAR "BIFF"; fi

You can't nest docker build instructions, everything after the `RUN` instruction gets executed in the image context, docker build commands don't
exist there. So that explains the error you are seeing.

Even you if you translated that to proper shell code `BAR` would only be active for that *single* `RUN` instruction during the build.

Either orchestrate on the host and pass `BAR` via `run -e` to your container or add a startup script to the image that sets `BAR` as needed on container start:

```
FROM foo
COPY my-start.sh /
CMD ["/my-start.sh"]
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can't embed Docker build command into shell of `RUN`, the shell will run inside the intermediate container during build process, and Docker build commands will be ran by Docker build engine, they're different things. And besides, Docker does not support conditional commands like `IF` or something like that. Docker is about immutable infrastructure, Dockerfile is the definition of your image and it's supposed to be able to generate the same image no matter what build context it is in. And from the delivery perspective of view, the image is your deliverable build artifacts, if you want to deliver different stuff, then use different Dockerfile to build different images, otherwise if the differences is about the runtime, I think you could really consider postpone the `env` definition to the runtime with `-e` option of `docker run`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your build is failing has been explained by @shizhz & @Erik Dannenberk.

However, if you do really need that behavior I suggest you make a little script to do that:

```
export BAR=`[[ hostname = "foo" ]] && echo "BAZ" || echo "BIFF"`

docker build -t hello/hi - <<EOF
FROM alpine
ENV BAR $BAR
CMD echo $BAR
EOF
```